# Scheme function that deletes member from list and sublists

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, member

First off, if anyone can find a question where this has already been answered, let me know. All I can find are functions that remove duplicates.

Anyhow, I am trying to write a scheme function `(delete V L)` that takes a value and a list as arguments, and removes that value from the list and all its sublists. For example, given the following input:

```
> (deep-delete 3 '(1 2 3 (4 3) 5 (6 (3 7)) 8))
```

It would yield:

```
(1 2 (4) 5 (6 (7)) 8)
```

So far, this is what I have written, but I know that the if statement (which is to check to see if the element is a sub-list, which implies it too must be operated on) must be placed incorrectly. Also, I cannot wrap my brain around where I should be using `cons` and where I shouldn't, because I'm still confused about tracking the return values of the recursion. Can someone please take a look and explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
(define (delete V L)
   (if (list? (car L)) (cons (delete V (car L) (cdr L)))     
   (cond
      ((null? L) L)
      ((equal? V (car L)) (delete V (cdr L)))
      (else (cons (car L) (delete V (cdr L))))))))
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a few comments on your code:

- First, in your `if` statement you use `(car L)` without checking if `L` is empty.
- Also, in line 2 of your code, you do: `(delete V (car L) (cdr L))`,
  but `cons` takes two arguments, not three. And you forgot to recursively call `delete` on the `cdr`.
  You wanted:
  `(cons (delete V (car L)) (delete V (cdr L)))`
- Why not use a single `cond`? Since there are several cases, using `cond` will make the recursive structure of your algorithm more apparent, and errors easier to catch.

See below.

```
(define (del V L)
  (cond ((null? L) L)
        ((list? (car L))
         (cons (del V (car L)) (del V (cdr L))))
        ((equal? V (car L)) (del V (cdr L)))
        (else (cons (car L) (del V (cdr L))))))
```

This will recursively delete `V` from `L`.

```
(del 3 '(1 2 3 (4 3) 5 (6 (3 7)) 8))
==> (1 2 (4) 5 (6 (7)) 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to achieve with folding; here's an example in Racket using `foldr`:

```
(define (deep-delete elt lst (test equal?))
  (foldr (lambda (e r)
           (if (list? e)
               (cons (deep-delete elt e test) r)
               (if (test elt e) r (cons e r))))
         null
         lst))
```

testing

```
> (deep-delete 3 '(1 2 3 (4 3) 5 (6 (3 7)) 8))
'(1 2 (4) 5 (6 (7)) 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

This removes subtrees from a tree (including atomic ones):

```
(define (remove-element needle haystack)
  (let rec ((haystack haystack))
    (cond 
      ((equal? needle haystack) '())
      ((not (pair? haystack)) haystack)
      ((equal? needle (car haystack)) (rec (cdr haystack)))
      ((equal? needle (cdr haystack)) (cons (rec (car haystack)) '()))
      (else (cons (rec (car haystack))
                  (rec (cdr haystack)))))))

(remove-element 'atom 'atom)               ; => ()    
(remove-element '(1 2 3) '((1 2 3) 1 2 3)) ; => ()
(remove-element '(1 2 3) '((1 2 3) 4 5 6)) ; => (4 5 6)
(remove-element '(1 2 3) '(3 2 1 2 3))     ; ==> (3 2)
(remove-element '3 '((1 2 3) 1 2 3))       ; ==> ((1 2) 1 2)
(remove-element '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))       ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```